# Read and interpret crontab with Perl

Tags: perl, date, cron

I'm writing a Perl program to check if and make sure that some system backup tasks were executed from crontab.

I need to read the crontab and interpret when it was supposed to run, in order to check if that backup was done. Here is an example.

```
00 03 * * 6 system_backup.sh
```

Let's suppose this task will generate a file called `system_backup_20180510.iso`

Then my idea was to store a "desirable date" into a var then compare with that date in the filename. The biggest issue is how to build that desirable date with crontab's day of month field filled up.

What you guys can suggest? Thanks

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Schedule::Cron::Events  will parse a crontab entry and tell you the next/previous times it would run.

Answer (score 0):

Note the 5th field: this only runs on Saturday.

Here's something you can do with GNU date:

```
$ date -d "-1 week saturday 03:00" "+%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"
20180505 03:00:00

$ date -d "-w week saturday 03:00" "+%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"
20180518 13:00:00

$ date -d "-2 week saturday 03:00" "+%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"
20180428 03:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

the Schedule::Cron::Events suggestion implemented:

```
crontab -l | perl -MPOSIX=strftime -MSchedule::Cron::Events -lne '
    $cron = Schedule::Cron::Events->new($_);
    $prev = strftime("%F %T", $cron->previousEvent());
    print "$prev => ", $cron->commandLine();
'
```